# Generar url de imagen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

estoy subiendo imágenes a mi proyecto de rails ( no estoy usando gemas), los subo a `public/temp` hasta aquí todo bien, el problema que tengo es que necesito generar una url publica de la imagen para que la foto pueda ser accedida por otro servicio.

este es mi codigo:

```
    base_url = "public/temp"
    require 'fileutils'
    FileUtils::mkdir_p base_url

    file_name = params[:image].original_filename
    path = File.join(base_url, file_name)
    File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(params[:image].read) }
```

hasta el momento probe con esto: `ActionController::Base.helpers.path_to_image("#{base_url}/#{file_name}")`  pero no me funciona, me genera esto `/images/public/temp/foto.jpg` pero me la toma como una ruta de rails.

lo que necesito es que se genere algo así: `https:my_url/url_imagen` y que se pueda acceder desde cualquier otro lugar.

Esto me genera el log de mi app:

```
{"status":404,"error":"Not Found","exception":"#\u003cActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] \"/temp/foto.jpg\"\u003e","traces":{"Application Trace":[],"Framework Trace":[{"id":0,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'"},{"id":1,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'"},{"id":2,"trace":"railties (5.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'"},{"id":3,"trace":"railties (5.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'"},{"id":4,"trace":"activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'"},{"id":5,"trace":"activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'"},{"id":6,"trace":"activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'"},{"id":7,"trace":"railties (5.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'"},{"id":8,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'"},{"id":9,"trace":"rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'"},{"id":10,"trace":"activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'"},{"id":11,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'"},{"id":12,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'"},{"id":13,"trace":"rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'"},{"id":14,"trace":"rack-cors (1.0.2) lib/rack/cors.rb:97:in `call'"},{"id":15,"trace":"railties (5.0.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'"},{"id":16,"trace":"puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'"},{"id":17,"trace":"puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:632:in `handle_request'"},{"id":18,"trace":"puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:446:in `process_client'"},{"id":19,"trace":"puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:306:in `block in run'"},{"id":20,"trace":"puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `call'"},{"id":21,"trace":"puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'"}],"Full Trace":[{"id":0,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'"},{"id":1,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'"},{"id":2,"trace":"railties (5.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'"},{"id":3,"trace":"railties (5.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'"},{"id":4,"trace":"activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'"},{"id":5,"trace":"activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'"},{"id":6,"trace":"activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'"},{"id":7,"trace":"railties (5.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'"},{"id":8,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'"},{"id":9,"trace":"rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'"},{"id":10,"trace":"activesupport (5.0.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'"},{"id":11,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'"},{"id":12,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'"},{"id":13,"trace":"rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'"},{"id":14,"trace":"rack-cors (1.0.2) lib/rack/cors.rb:97:in `call'"},{"id":15,"trace":"railties (5.0.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'"},{"id":16,"trace":"puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'"},{"id":17,"trace":"puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:632:in `handle_request'"},{"id":18,"trace":"puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:446:in `process_client'"},{"id":19,"trace":"puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:306:in `block in run'"},{"id":20,"trace":"puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `call'"},{"id":21,"trace":"puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'"}]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías ocupar algunos de los métodos de la instancia de `request` disponibles a nivel de controlador. Por ejemplo:

```
request.host # "localhost"
request.host_with_port # "localhost:3000"
request.url # "http://localhost:3000/"
```

Otras opciones que puedes usar, puedes encontrarlas en la [documentación de rails](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/URL.html).

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción es utilizar `root_url`, el cual te da la URL raíz de la aplicación; en tu caso, por ser desarrollo, te daría `http://localhost:3000/`; y podrías utilizarlo así:

```
"#{root_url}temp/#{params[:image].original_filename}"
```

Recuerda que puedes solicitar los archivos del directorio `public` a través de la raíz de tu sitio; en tu caso, para solicitar algún archivo dentro de `public/temp` basta con utilizar `http://localhost:3000/temp`.

Comment: haciendo eso me lo toma como una ruta de rails y me da error 404.

Comment: @mariovzc ¿Podrías compartir el log del error?

Comment: claro que si ya actualizo mi pregunta.